# WordPress count posts on archive pages

Tags: wordpress, elementor, custom-taxonomy

I have this shortcode which displays total number of posts from a custom taxonomy, but I need it to work on Archive pages, so if I don't put an ID to the shortcode, it doesn't display.

```
function category_product_count_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts );

    $category = get_term( $atts['id'], 'product_cat' );
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = $query->post_count;
    
    return $count;
    
}
add_shortcode( 'category_product_count', 'category_product_count_shortcode' );
```

Shortcode would be `[category_product_count id="12"]`

Comment: [WP_Query > properties](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified of your code. You have to get category from the archive page.

```
function category_product_count_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts );

    // Check if ID parameter is provided, if not, get the category from the current Archive page
    if ( empty( $atts['id'] ) && is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $category = get_queried_object();
    } else {
        $category = get_term( $atts['id'], 'product_cat' );
    }

    if ( ! $category ) {
        return ''; // Return an empty string if the category is not found
    }

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = $query->post_count;

    return $count;
}
add_shortcode( 'category_product_count', 'category_product_count_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if `$atts['id']` exists and if so construct the `tax_query` array.

```
function category_product_count_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => '',
    ), $atts );

    $tax_query = array();

    if( $atts['id'] ) {
        $category = get_term( $atts['id'], 'product_cat' );
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $category->term_id,
        );
    }
    
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => $tax_query,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = $query->post_count;
    
    return $count
    
}
add_shortcode( 'category_product_count', 'category_product_count_shortcode' );
```

Comment: It returns all the posts from that taxonomy